# EF Code First CTP 5 and SQL SErver 2008 R2

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2008-r2, code-first

I can't seem to get the EF Code First to work with SQL Server 2008 R2. The error I am getting is "Invalid object name 'dbo.Movies'."

It is not creating the table automatically.

My connection string:

`<add name="MovieDBContext"
         connectionString="Server=(local); Database=Movies; Trusted_Connection=true; Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

My model and context class:

```
public class Movie
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Date is required")]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Genre must be specified")]
    public string Genre { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Price Required")]
    [Range(1, 100, ErrorMessage = "Price must be between $1 and $100")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [StringLength(5)]
    public string Rating { get; set; }

}

public class MovieDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Movie>().Property(p => p.Price).HasPrecision(18, 2);
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I forget if it's enabled by default but try setting this in your `Application_Start` (pretty sure it's not)

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.DbDatabase.SetInitializer<MovieDBContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MovieDBContext>());
```

Comment: That was not that in my Application_Start method, but it did not seem to make it work.

Comment: Check to see it the table already exists and if it already exists then you need to make sure that the table names match. (Or delete the table and let EF build it for you) otherwise we're missing something as the above method, when called in Application_Start would work.

Comment: I went back and redid a lot of the tutorial i followed + did what you suggested and it now works. 

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Heres my current setup (replace caps with your details):

```
      <connectionStrings>
         <add name="TITLEContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.TITLE.csdl|res://*/Models.TITLE.ssdl|res://*/Models.TITLE.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=DATASOURCE;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

And then I followed up with this in the Public TITLEContext()

```
DbDatabase.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<TITLEContext>());
```

Took a couple tries, but put a break point on one of your loads and check the context's entities. It should have an optiont o see the database connection string...

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}
```

hope it helps